# PHP escaping qoutes

Tags: php

Just a simple line:

```
print "<li class=\"productImage\"style=\"background-image: url(\"images/products/1.jpg\");\">";
```

And the output is:

```
<li 1.jpg");"="" products="" images="" style="background-image: url(" class="productImage"><img src="images/products/2.jpg"></li>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Fixed:

```
print '<li class="productImage" style="background-image: url(\'images/products/1.jpg\');">';
```

Comment: Why are you escaping every quote?
Should be like this:
print "<li class='productImage'  etc etc  <li/>"

Comment: Quotes from `url` are closing the `style`.

Comment: Try like this: `print "<li class='productImage' style='background-image: url(\"images/products/1.jpg\");'>";`

Comment: or `print "<li class=\"productImage\"style=\"background-image: url('images/products/1.jpg');\">";` ~ you don't need the double quotes within the `url()` that was breaking it

Comment: Thanx! Haven't realised, that the style attribute gets closed and messes everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with proper escape sequences, using same quotes are misjudged by browser (style in your case):

```
print "<li class='productImage' style='background-image: url(\"images/products/1.jpg\");'>";
```